# Query on InfoPath data storage

Tags: infopath

I have a query on InfoPath 2013 forms. I have designed an InfoPath 2013 form where there are large number of fields (controls) where data would reside, like text-boxes, drop-down, etc.
My concern is, should I continue to hold the data on InfoPath form itself or should I save the data to a custom list and retrieve from there while the form is being rendered?

Which is the better one in terms of performance, holding the data on form or saving to and retrieving from a custom list/form library?

I am little confused regarding the saving of data... where does the data of InfoPath resides? So please help me to clear my doubts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zakir,

[Comparing SharePoint List and Form Library Forms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/22/comparing-list-and-form-library-forms.aspx) , this post answers your question.

An excerpt from the article:

> **SharePoint list forms** store data directly in a SharePoint list.  Each control (e.g. text box) in the form is bound to a column in the
> list. SharePoint list forms are directly connected to the list, which
> means that you don’t have to worry about setting up the publish and
> submit locations.
>
> **Form library forms** store data in XML files in a SharePoint form library. This means they are more flexible and you can do more with
> them. For example, they can be configured to save drafts and submit to
> different locations. However, they are more complex to work with and
> require more decisions to be made during configuration.

**EDIT**
MSDN explains best practices for using InfoPath
[Building SharePoint Applications with InfoPath 2010 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961896.aspx)
[Building SharePoint Applications with InfoPath 2010 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961895.aspx)

Comment: Dear Arsalan, many thanks for the reference. So the data is hold on InfoPath form when submitted to form library? Am I right?

Comment: Yes the data is within InfoPath form, or you can extend it to Library Columns as well.. but repeating tables and other complex controls are within InfoPath stored as XML at back-end